# Limit of "simple" function

Tags: limits, functions

I am trying to solve:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} ({1 - \sin x})^{\cot2x}$$

I know that this could be solved by different methods.
Can anyone summarize the methods and give me some references to read?

Thanks!

PS: This is the way I started first
$$\lim_{x\to 0} ({1 - \sin x})^{\cot2x} = \lim_{x\to 0} e^{(1 - \sin x)\ln{\cot2x}} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln{\cot{2x}}}{\frac{1}{1 - \sin x}}$$
Then I am trying Leibniz's theorem but I end up nowhere.

Comment: Watch that: on the LHS you have $\,1-\sin x\,$ ,whether on the RHS you wrote $\,1+\sin x\,$

Comment: just a typo sorry

Comment: FYI: One solves equations, but one *computes* limits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y= ({1 - \sin x})^{\cot 2x}$$

So, $$\ln y=\cot 2x\ln(1-\sin x)=-\frac12 \frac{\cos 2x}{\cos x} \frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{-\sin x} $$

So, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln y=-\frac12 \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos 2x}{\cos x} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{-\sin x}$$

Now,  $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-\sin x)}{-\sin x}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+z)}z=1$ putting $z=-\sin x$ and $z\to 0$ as $x\to 0$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln y=-\frac12$$

Hence, $$\lim_{x\to 0} y=e^{-\frac12}$$

Answer (score 1):

May be you didn't see this approach as @Brian M. Scott proved it for me kindly, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195093/8581. As we see,  your limit is as $1^{\infty}$ when $x\to 0$ so by using that elegant result: $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1-\sin x)^{\cot(2x)}=\text{e}^{\lim_{x\to 0}(-\sin x)\cot(2x)}=\text{e}^{\lim_{x\to 0}-\cos(2x)/2\cos(x)}=\text{e}^{-1/2}, x\neq0$$

Comment: Careful: your exponential power is lacking both a $\,1\,$ and a logarithm: $$a^b=e^{b\log a}$$

Comment: @Babak, you seem to have done the same as Adi: you passed to the limit $\,(1-\sin x)^{\sin x}\to e^{-1}\,$ while, *at the same time*, the remaining part of the exponent did NOT move and $\,x\,$ remained. This requires justification.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} ({1 - \sin x})^{\cot2x}=\lim_{x\to 0} ({1 - \sin x})^{{1\over \sin x}\cot2x\sin x}$$
$$=\exp(-\lim_{x\to 0}\cot2x\sin x)=\exp\left(-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos2x}{\sin2x}\sin x\right)=$$
$$=\exp\left(-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2}{2\sin x\cos x}\sin x\right)=\exp\left(-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{2\cos x}\right)=e^{-1/2}$$

Comment: What happened to the logarithm that must be there in the exponential function's power?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0} ({1 - \sin x})^{{1\over \sin x}}=e^{-1}$$ so no need logarithm

Comment: But then you need to justify, and I'm not sure whether thi is possible, how in the power you took the limit of a part of the exponent to get $\,e^{-1}\,$ while the other part of it remained with $\,x\,$ *and without going to the limit* at the same time...

Comment: @AdiDani: What do you think about Don's comments? Thanks Adi.