# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln x}{f(x)}\right)^{f(x)/x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, contest-math

Let's consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(0,\infty)$, with $f(x)\cdot \ln f(x)=e^x$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then compute

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln x}{f(x)}\right)^{\dfrac{f(x)}{x}}$$

**The first solution**

Since 
$$f(x)\cdot \ln f(x)=e^x, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
we may easily deduce that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$
On the other hand
$$f^2(x)> f(x)\cdot \ln f(x)=e^x$$
$$f(x)> e^{x/2}$$
and then 
$$0\le\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x}{f(x)}\le\frac{\ln x}{e^{x/2}}\rightarrow 0$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x}{f(x)}=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \displaystyle\frac{e^{x/2}}{x} \le \lim_{x\to\infty} \displaystyle\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$$

At this point we recognize that our limit case is $1^{\infty}$, and have 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln x}{f(x)}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{f(x)}{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\displaystyle \frac{\ln x}{x }}=e^0=1$$

**The second solution** (from a brilliant friend of mine - - so sorry I missed this way)

Let's take log of both sides of the limit

$$\ln L = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{\ln x} \ln \left(1+\frac{\ln x}{f(x)}\right)\times \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x}=1\times 0=0$$
that is simply justified by the fact that $f(x)>>x$ (see $f(x)> e^{x/2}$)

**Question**: how would you approach this question? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing us bunch of interesting problems, sis. +1

Comment: @BabakS.: I'm glad you like them! :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very good point knowing that if $$\lim_{x\to{+\infty}} f(x)^{g(x)}=1^{+\infty}$$ which is indeterminate limit then we can solve it by taking the following limit:  $$k =\lim_{x\to +\infty}\big(f(x)-1\big)g(x)$$ instead. So $$\lim_{x\to{+\infty}} f(x)^{g(x)}=e^k$$

Now, try to use this formula also. It gives you $~~\text{e}~~$ at last. For more see how @Brian proved me that. This proof deserves more that +100. [100](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/195093/8581)

Comment: Thanks for your work. (+1)

Comment: Good day, Babak! :+)

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{\ln x}{f(x)}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{f(x)}{x}}$

$\left(1+\frac{x}{f(e^x)}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{f(e^x)}{e^x}} =  \left(\left(1+\frac{x}{f(e^x)}\right)^{\displaystyle f(e^x)}\right)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{e^x}} \sim\big(e^x\big)^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{e^x}} = \big(e\big)^{\displaystyle\frac{x}{e^x}} \to e^0 = 1$

The substitution $x \leftarrow e^x$ is justified by the fact that $x \to +\infty \Leftrightarrow e^x \to +\infty$

The $\sim$ by the fact that $f(e^x) \to +\infty$ (not completely sure about that)

And the rest is simple.

Comment: Why substitute $\log x = t$ (is this what you meant to do?) when the rest of the manipulation can be done without it?

Comment: @Alex: How do you get $\left(1+\frac{x}{y}\right)^y$ then?

Comment: If $f(x) \to \infty$, then $(1+\frac{\log x}{f(x)})^{f(x)}$ and $(1+\frac{t}{f(e^t)})^{f(e(t)}$ are the same, although I'm not sure at all that this is approximation using the definition of $e$ is correct at all, as the OP's expression involves $x$ both in the numerator ($\log x$) and the denominator of the power.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to notice that $f$ is differentiable: Differentiating the equation for $f$ with respect to $f$ (we're going to use the inverse function theorem here, so we're thinking of $x$ as a function of $f$) and dividing through by $e^x$ we get
$$\frac{dx}{df}= \frac{1+\ln{f}}{e^x}=\frac{1+\frac{e^x}{f}}{e^x}.$$
But $f$ is by definition always positive. Therefore, the $dx/df$ can never be zero, which by the inverse function theorem means that $f$ must always be differentiable. Moreover, since $dx/df$ is always positive, so is $df/dx$, which means--and here's the punch line--that $f$ is (strictly) monotone increasing.

So, now let's try and find some bounds on $f$. Since $f$ is monotone increasing, it's going to eventually be strictly positive (in fact it one can show that it'll *always* be positive, but that's not going to be important to us), so we can use the fact that $\ln{x}<x$ for all $x>0$ to get that $\ln{f(x)}<f(x)$ for large enough $x$. Therefore, returning to the defining equation for $f$, we get the two inequalities
$$e^x=f(x)\ln{f(x)}\leq f(x)^2$$
and 
$$e^x\geq[\ln{f(x)}]^2.$$
These simplify to 
$$e^{x/2}\leq f(x) \leq e^{e^{x/2}}.$$

Finally, let's head over to our limit, the inside of which I'll call $y$. Taking the natural log, we get
$$\ln{y} = \frac{f(x)}{x}\ln\left(1+\frac{\ln{x}}{f(x)}\right).$$
Using $f(x)\geq e^{x/2}$, we can get rid of the $f(x)$ outside of the $\ln$, and using $f(x)\leq e^{e^{x/2}}$, we can get rid of the one inside. This gives 
$$\ln{y} \leq \frac{e^{x/2}}{x} \ln\left(1+e^{-e^{x/2}}\log{x}\right),$$
which I'll leave to you to show approaches $0$ as $x\to \infty$.

We'd like to simply stop here and say that $\ln{y}$ must also approach $0$, but this only works if $\ln{y}$ is (eventually) nonnegative---then we can use the squeeze theorem to conclude that yes, $\ln{y}$ does in fact approach $0$. So, is $\ln{y}$ nonnegative? Well, let's look back at the original equation for $\ln{y}$. Since $f$ is always positive, the part outside the $\ln$ is also positive (as long as $x>0$, but we're working with large $x$ here, so we can assume this). The same reasoning tells us that the part inside the $\ln$ must be greater than $1$ (as long as $x>1$, but again, we can assume this), and hence that the $\ln$ part itself is positive. Thus, $\ln{y}$ is indeed positive, and we get that $\ln{y}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Hence, 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{\ln{x}}{f(x)}\right)^{\dfrac{f(x)}{x}}=1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your work. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Since $g(y) =y\log y$ is strictly increasing for $y>1$ it follows that there is an inverse function $h$ which is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty) $.

Now the given function $f$ is given by $f(x) =h(e^x) $ and clearly $f(x) \to\infty $ as $x\to\infty $. The given limit is easily handled by putting $t=f(x) $ so that $x=\log g(t) =\log(t\log t) $ and then the desired limit is $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{\log\log(t\log t)} {t} \right) ^{t/\log(t\log t)} $$ Since $\dfrac{\log\log(t\log t)}{t} \to 0$ it follows that the desired limit equals $$\exp\left(\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\log\log(t\log t)} {\log(t\log t)} \right) =e^0=1$$