# Evaluation of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can anyone help me in solving the limit problem:

$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: @mezhang This is definitely a case of the indeterminate form $1^\infty$ in a limit. Your limit is not of this form. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Answer (score 6):

There’s a standard trick for dealing with such limits. Let $$y=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\;.$$

Then

$$\ln y=\sqrt{n}\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{n^{-1/2}}\;.$$

The log is continuous, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln y=\ln\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y$, and therefore

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}y=e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln y}\;.$$

Now use l’Hospital’s rule to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln y$.

(In this problem one can actually avoid these calculations by making use of the fact that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e\;,$$

but the general method is worth knowing.)

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left (1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n}{n}}=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at this alternative approach. I asked it ago and got @Brian's concrete answer. This is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195092/8581). According to it you would have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+1/n\right)^{\sqrt{n}}=\exp(k)$$ wherein $$k=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\big(1+1/n-1\big)\sqrt{n}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^{\sqrt{n}/n}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 y = \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^{\sqrt n }  \Leftrightarrow y = {\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{\sqrt n \ln \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}  \\ 
 \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^{\sqrt n }  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } {\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{\sqrt n \ln \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}  = {\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sqrt n \ln \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)}  = e^0  = 1 \\ 
 \end{array}
$$